# Why whould total partitions be 1 and scanned partitions a bigger number in this job run?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting that scanned partitions is bigger than total, but reading the docs the interpretation is the other way around

[image: Partitions]

Any idea on the rationale?

The query is (from the docs):

```
create or replace table save_copy_errors as select * from
table(validate(mycsvtable, job_id=>'<query_id>'));
```

Comment: For a COPY command that I have found in my history with the same looking profile, where we load 3 rows, we have a 3 coming out of the `ExternalScan[1]` (which for us is a S3 bucket via a stage) and the same 1 coming out of the `Insert[2]` block, but we have not partition action. I wonder if you table destination table is small but was fragmented, and it got rewritten by the operation.

Comment: Can you share the query?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa added, thanks